# Hackerrank Dynamic Array Timeout

Tags: java

I was working on the Data Structures track on Hackerrank, when I came across this [challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/dynamic-array?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen).

I think my code works, but I am getting timeout issues. That is, it seems to be taking too long to run on inputs with a lot of queries. Here is my first shot at a solution (with the timeout issues):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int q = sc.nextInt();
    ArrayList<Integer>[] group = (ArrayList<Integer>[])new ArrayList[n];
    int lastAns = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> curr = null;
    //int currVal = 0;

    for(int i = 0;i < q;i++){
        int query = sc.nextInt();
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        int y = sc.nextInt();
        int thing = (x^lastAns) % n;

        if(query == 1){
            if(group[thing] == null){
                group[thing] = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);
            }
            curr = group[thing];
            curr.add(y);
        }else if(query == 2){

            curr = group[thing];
            lastAns = curr.get(y % curr.size());
            System.out.println(lastAns);
        }
    }
    sc.close();
}
}
```

Here is code that worked with no timeout issues:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int q = sc.nextInt();
    int lastAns = 0;
    ArrayList<ArrayList> group = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<Integer> curr = null;
    //int currVal = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        group.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }

    for(int i = 0;i < q;i++){
        int query = sc.nextInt();
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        int y = sc.nextInt();
        int thing = (x^lastAns) % n;

        if(query == 1){
            curr = group.get(thing);
            curr.add(y);
        }else if(query == 2){

            curr = group.get(thing);
            lastAns = curr.get(y % curr.size());
            System.out.println(lastAns);
        }
    }        
    sc.close();
}
}
```

My question is: What is the difference here that resolved the timeout issues? My first guess is that arrays take longer to access/change elements than ArrayLists. Is this the case?

Comment: Probably not. The one thing where an `ArrayList` is slower is if you know the size you need, but instead of preallocating the size with the proper constructor, you create one with the default size. When adding a lot of things the `ArrayList` needs to resize itself, which can be a source of slowness. There's no noticeable speed difference when accessing the elements (and arrays would be faster anyway, not the other way around).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key difference I see is that in the poorly-performing code, you're giving each *inner* `ArrayList<Integer>` an initial size of `n`, whereas in the other code you're only giving that initial size to the outer list:

```
group[thing] = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);
```

vs

```
group.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

I'm guessing this was a mistake, and by forcing each of the inner lists to have size `n` you're making the memory space required by this algorithm `O(n²)`.